# Haskell: depth-first search for ordered tree

Tags: haskell, tree, depth-first-search

First of all, I have a data type for ordered trees:

```
data OrdTree a = OrdTree a [OrdTree a]
                    deriving (Show)
```

I need to get a list of all nodes in order of DFS (depth-first search).

Here is my attempt to solve this:

```
dfsTreeList :: OrdTree a ->  [a]                       
dfsTreeList (OrdTree a (x:xt)) = a : (dfsTreeList x) ++ (dfsTreeList (OrdTree a xt))                          
dfsTreeList (OrdTree a []) = a : []
```

But a new problem appears: every non-last node is included in the list twice.

For instance, input data:

```
dfsTreeList (OrdTree 7 [(OrdTree 3 [(OrdTree 1 []), (OrdTree 4 [])]), (OrdTree 10 [(OrdTree 8 []), (OrdTree 12 [])])])
```

And result:

```
[7,3,1,3,4,3,7,10,8,10,12,10,7]
```

Does someone have any ideas? Thanks for any reply.

Comment: look closely here: `++ (dfsTreeList (OrdTree a xt))`... why do you insert the `a` again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
dfsTreeList (OrdTree a (x:xt)) = a : (dfsTreeList x) ++ (dfsTreeList (OrdTree a xt))
```

you are duplicating the `a`. You could try applying the function to every subtree in the list, e.g.

```
dfsTreeList (OrdTree a xs) = a : concat (map dfsTreeList xs)
```

You can also use `concatMap` or `>>=` to the same effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I totally forgot about 'concat' function. :)